# Virtual to Kernel logical address

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a char driver in which one of the interface functions I added is `alloc_contig(int order)` where order is log2 of desired number of 4K pages.
This function allocates contiguous physical memory and maps it for userspace usage using `remap_pfn_range` function.
I'm trying to write function which frees this memory `dealloc_contig(va)`
now in Kernel I have the virtual address given by user to free and I need to obtain the underlying physical address, so I tried to use `virt_to_phys` but it is not giving me the desired address.
Log:

```
//allocating
page address is ffff880868764000 //allocated using alloc_pages
//deallocating
virtual address from user 7f4c7e095000
when converted to PA using virt_to_phys got f74c7e095000 instead of ffff880868764000
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

**Quick answer**: You have to use **do_munmap()** to unmap the pages from the user process.
**virt_to_phys()** can't do this job. It is used by the kernel to translate
kernel virtual address(not user virtual address) to physical address.

User space memories are organized by vma regions.(**struct vm_area_struct *vma**).
They can be found under struct mm_struct on per process basis. Processes
have their own mm_structs so that the same virtual address for different processes mapped to different physcial addresses.

What you need to do is, get the virtual address. Then,in kernel space, you need to
find out which vma this address belongs to, then unmap the address range
from the vma and reclaim the pages.(This is what **do_munmap()** do.).

Another point worth mentioned is,because processes have their own mm_struct, thus their own vma regions. do_munmap()
have to be called under the "correct" user process conext, or it will get the wrong mm_struct.

Sum up the steps:
1.User process which have mapped the region call 
  your interface to release the virtual address.
2.System call to kernel space(This is under your user process' context). Your driver handler call do_munmap() to 
  unmap the virtual address.
3.Your driver free the pages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Can you please, if possible, guide me on how to find the appropriate vma struct? As I saw, in mm_strct there is red black tree called mm_rb containing vma structs. So how do I access mm_struct of the process and how do I search in this tree?

Comment: Hi, This is done by do_munmap() -->find_vma(), you can look at the source code at this link. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/mmap.c#L2411